# Going after investors

Tags: united-states, civil-law, liability

Now that companies are on the verge of collapse from PFAS litigation, is it okay to go after investors? If Blackrock invests in Exxon then are they liable for anything Exxon does?

Comment: So, what is your question, whether it is allowed to file lawsuits?

Comment: @Greendrake It seems fairly obvious that OP wants to know whether/how a claim against the investors could be viable.

Answer (score 2):

Under US Law, the liability of investors is limited to the value of their equity.

In other words, their share price can go to Zero if the company faces massive judgements. But plaintiffs (victims) cannot then pursue investors for their individual bank accounts and property.

Comment: That's called **limited liability**  - e.g. the liability of the investor is limited to the amount they invested.

Comment: Limited liability doesn't apply to negligent or illegal behavior, just to debt collection.

Comment: @UkraineTank - and most people who bought the stock are not in a position to have been negligent or done illegal things as an agent of the company. They are not behind the 'corporate veil' at all.

Answer (score 2):

### Investors are not liable for the actions of the company

The entire purpose of a limited liability corporation is to protect the investors from anything the company does. It doesn’t matter if the company breaks the law or even if it deliberately and knowingly engages in criminal actions.

In certain circumstances it is possible to “pierce the corporate veil” and prosecute or sue directors or others who exert control over the company, but for a passive investor who just bought shares on a stock exchange, no.